# Angular 6: Scroll to element on click from child component side-nav

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular6

I am using A6 router in where I am rendering 3 components on /new route. I am also using [Angular-material](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples) and using the sidenav component. My parentComponent is the main content area and the childComponent is the drawer content.

```
  {
    path: 'new',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ParentComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: SiblingComponent,
        outlet: 'nav',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: ChildComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

childComponent html

```
<div class="new-event-side-nav">
  <mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item>
    <span>Some Details</span>
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item [href]="otherDetail">
    <span>Other Details</span>
    </a>
  </mat-nav-list>
</div>
```

parentComponent

```
<mat-card>
    <div id="some_detail">
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="other_detail">
      <p>Other Content</p>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

I can extract the IDs of both divs in my child component using

```
otherDetail = document.getElementById('other_detail');
```

and inject it into my child component's html. But on click it's not scrolling down to the element, I'm getting a 404. Further more, my url changes from /new to **/%5Bobject%20HTMLDivElement%5D**

I'm new to scrolling to elements in Angular 6. Anyone have experience with scrolling to different elements using a sidenav from a child element?

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago I had the same challenge and I had to write my own solution. I was never very happy with it though - making auto-scrolling smooth and natural-looking was waaaay more complicated than I imagined (due to 'scrollTop' not being an animateable attribute). It led me down the rabbit hole of studying javascript 'easing functions' ... don't go that route.

If it comes down to it, you can bind to the scrollTop attribute of any div. If in a directive you might use HostBinding, i.e -

```
 @HostBinding('scrollTop') scrollTop : number = <<whatever...>>;
```

Or if its to a child element in the template you could just write normal attribute binding

```
 <div class="scrolling-div" [scrollTop]="scrollTop" ></div>
```

With that its simple enough to scroll the div up and down as needed - but it will basically be instant unless you manually animate it with timers / intervals. I combined this technique with a very simple link directive that I placed on every element I wanted to be able to scroll to. That link directive emitted its vertical position on the page (to give the scroller a destination) and also an event whenever it was clicked to alert the scroller. I was able to get mine looking just OK - no easing but there was linear animation that was tolerable  to look at. If you're set on writing your own solution let me know and I can share all the code I wrote back in the day

Comment: a working example can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7411